# What is unfortunate about the construction given in the following example?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, temporary-objects

Section "15.6.2 Initializing bases and members" (N4713) has the following example following item 11:

```
struct A {
    A() = default; // OK
    A(int v) : v(v) { } // OK
    const int& v = 42; // OK
};
A a1; // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
A a2(1); // OK, unfortunately
```

What is **unfortunate** about the construction in the last line of the example?

I searched the whole reference for other occurrences of "unfortunate" behaviour that were permitted but I could find none.

If it was unfortunate in this particular context, could it not have been made illegal?

Comment: by "OK, unfortunately" it actually means "not OK but the compiler isn't required to warn"

Comment: Yeah it means "You don't want this to happen and it would be nice if it had errored, but it won't/can't/something"

Comment: A link to the latest draft : http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#11

Comment: I think it's not illegal because there is nothing wrong with it so long as you only access the `v` member inside the constructor. (It doesn't make sense to write such code, but C++ doesn't disallow programs just because they don't make sense.)

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that the code is ill-formed, and that the compiler is not required to emit a diagnostic.  Diagnostics are generally not required if it would burden the compiler with excessive effort (static analysis) to discover the violation, or when it would not be possible.  C++ puts a lot of that burden on the programmer; C++ is not a nanny language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both case `A::v` is dangling reference (temporary from 42, or parameter `v` of constructor).

Having reference to temporary (even with extended lifetime) might be legal and correctly used in some cases.

Hard to detect all misuse cases to forbid them.

Comment: If anything I'm a little confused as to what makes the first declaration ill-formed

Comment: Then why is it "OK" in the first case and only "OK, unfortunately" in the second?

Comment: @P.W - Remember that code examples in the standard are non-normative. It's not "OK" meaning "good". It's "OK" in the sense that it doesn't violate any standard rule, and therefore isn't ill-formed. Nothing in the example is really "OK".

Comment: @StoryTeller: Even with the sense you suggest, the question still stands. Why differentiate between the two cases?