# Validity and/or lifetime extension of mem-initializer in aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, lifetime, temporary-objects

CWG 1815 [asked](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1815) (with minor edits):

> ```
> struct A {};
> struct B { A&& a = A{}; };
> B b1;         // #1
> B b2{A{}};    // #2
> B b3{};       // #3
> ```
>
> [...] `#2` is aggregate initialization, which binds `B::a` to the temporary in the initializer for `b2` and thus extends its lifetime to that of `b2`. `#3` is aggregate initialization, but it is not clear whether the lifetime of the temporary in the non-static data member initializer for `B::a` should be lifetime-extended like `#2` or not, like `#1`.

Per the Notes on that issue, at Issaquah (2014-02) CWG intended to make `#3` behave like `#2`; that is, well-formed, and performing lifetime extension of the temporary to which `b3.a` binds. But at the next ISO meeting (Rapperswil, 2014-06) the resolution to [CWG 1696](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1696) was adopted, ostensibly resolving CWG 1815 but [adopting](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/c93a904986ca0cdf9cd02bc5aafc0da258d6a47b) language that [appears to make `#3` ill-formed](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#11):

> 11 - A temporary expression bound to a reference member from a default member initializer is ill-formed.

However, the example immediately under that clause does not consider aggregate initialization (as in CWG 1815) but only initialization by constructor; specifically, a default constructor defined as defaulted:

> ```
> struct A {
>   A() = default;        // OK
>   A(int v) : v(v) { }   // OK
>   const int& v = 42;    // OK
> };
> A a1;                   // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
> A a2(1);                // OK, unfortunately
> ```

So although the wording seems clear, it would also seem contrary to the intent of the Committee, which could be reason to consider the wording defective.

In terms of implementation practice, we can [see that](https://godbolt.org/z/K9rGsP) there is considerable variance:

|  | gcc | clang | MSVC | ICC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `#1` | ❌ destroy | ✅ reject | ☠️ leak | ❌ destroy |
| `#2` | ✅ extend | ✅ extend | ✅ extend | ✅ extend |
| `#3` | ❌ extend | ❌ extend | ❌ extend | ❌ destroy |

(Here, "destroy" means the temporary is destructed at the end of the declaration i.e. not lifetime-extended. ✅ indicates conformance, ❌ non-conformance, ☠️ a clear defect.) However, other than ICC, the compilers agree on extending lifetime in `#3`, contrary to the current wording. Oddly, despite performing lifetime extension, Clang *warns* that it is unable to do so, indicating that the developers consider lifetime extension to be required by the Standard in this case:

> warning: sorry, lifetime extension of temporary created by aggregate initialization using default member initializer is not supported; lifetime of temporary will end at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling]

#### Question

Given the expressed intent of CWG, and implementation variance, is it reasonable to consider the current wording as defective and to rely on lifetime extension occurring in `#3`? Are the Committee aware of this discrepancy and is there prospect of it being resolved in the near or medium term (as a DR to C++20, say)?

Comment: It seems to me from 1815 that the committee frowns on trying to initialize reference members via default member initializers at all. So it would be best for all involved to just not do that. Hence saying "OK, unfortunately" to one of the constructor examples that work.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's not initializing the reference member via a default member initializer, it's via a mem-initializer, to a lvalue that happens to be the constructor parameter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147940/what-is-unfortunate-about-the-construction-given-in-the-following-example

Comment: Is there _mem-initializer_ in aggregate initialization?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer no, *mem-initializer*s can only appear in a constructor definition.

Comment: Did you ever file a core issue about this? If not, you should. And if you don't want to, let me know and I'll do it (although if you let me do it, I can't promise that the resolution I propose is going to be what you want :P)

Comment: @BrianBi and I though I could get away with just carping on the sidelines ;) Thanks for the nudge, I've submitted a DR (and cc'd you).

Comment: This is now https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2669.html