# Lifetime extension of default initialized const ref& in an aggregate

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization, const-reference, default-initialization

I know that binding prvalues to const ref variables will extend the lifetime of the temporary. Now I thought I'd be clever to have a `struct options` that contains a const ref field `B_options` (which is used for initializing a subclass in my context). So when I copy this object into the class it will only take space of one reference instead of containing the whole subclass options as well. I compiled this code in gcc and it works perfectly well:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Astruct+B_options%0A%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+10%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+options%0A%7B%0A++++const+B_options%26+b_cfg+%3D+%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++options+cfg+%3D+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22b_cfg+%3D+%25d%22,+cfg.b_cfg.a)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os+-pthread%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

struct B_options
{
    int a = 10;
};

struct options
{
    const B_options& b_cfg = {};
};

int main()
{
    options cfg = {};

    printf("b_cfg = %d", cfg.b_cfg.a);
}
```

Then out of curiostiy I tried to compile it with clang trunk and out comes the following error:

```
<source>:15:20: warning: sorry, lifetime extension of temporary created by aggregate initialization using default member initializer is not supported; lifetime of temporary will end at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling]
    options cfg = {};
                   ^
<source>:10:22: note: initializing field 'b_cfg' with default member initializer
    const B_options& b_cfg = {};
```

Now... is this UB or just something that clang can't do right now? I'm on gcc so I could live with clang just not implementing stuff, but I'm not that comfy venturing to UB land.

Comment: Sorry, I've initially pasted the wrong link. I guess this may shed some light on the topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65528744/validity-and-or-lifetime-extension-of-mem-initializer-in-aggregate-initializatio
It's about rvalue references, but they behave analogically in terms of lifetime extension.

Comment: @alagner Interesting, apparently that is an ongoing discussion in [CWG](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2669.html). I would side with gcc and say this is well formed just because it is really handy x)

Comment: @glades, do you have a link to an active discussion on this subject?!

Comment: @Red.Wave I do not unfortunately.